# How is a decibel a tenth of a Bel?

Tags: ratio

By definition, one Bel is log<sub>10</sub>(P<sub>2</sub>/P<sub>1</sub>) (in the power example) and one dB is 10log<sub>10</sub>(P<sub>2</sub>/P<sub>1</sub>), so it appears to me that one dB is ten Bels, not one-tenth of a Bel.  Yet, many online publications, university publications, and others all seem to agree that one dB is one-tenth of a Bel.  How do they figure?  (And please don't say anything about the definition of the deci- prefix, which only clouds the explanation.)

Thanks!
Noji Ratzlaff
Orem, Utah

Comment: So, your example in parentheses shows that 10 Bels is one decibels, contradicting the statement "You need 10 dB to make one Bel"  Is that not correct?

Comment: When we express your height (say 8 feet) in feet vs inches. your height is 8 feet = 96 inches. So the number to represent your height in inches is $12$ times of that in feet. However, the unit itself "inch" is only 1/12 of "foot. The same thing happens to "bel" vs "dbel", if your express some intensity in "bel" vs "dbel", the number to present the intensity in "dbel" is $10$ times of that in "bel" but the unit itself "dbel" is only 1/10 of "bel".

Comment: I see...it's a conversion factor, not really an equation.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

One Bel is not $\log_{10}(P_2/P_2)$ (especially as this depends on $P_1$ and $P_2$). Rather, the *number* of Bels by which $P_2$ differes from $P_1$ is obtained by computing $\log_{10}(P_2/P_2)$. And *because* one dB is one tenth of one B, the *number* of decibels is ten times as large.

This is the same as that the number of decimeters is obtained by multiplying the number of meters that make a distance by $10$: I am $1.85$ meters tall, so I am $18.5$ decimeters tall (or $185$ centimeters, or $0.00185$ kilometers)

Comment: Ahh...the centimeters example really helped!  It's the *number of* that makes the difference.  In other words, even though 1 centimeter is 1/100 of a meter, it takes 100 times the *number of* meters to get *number of* centimeters.  Any by the same token, even though the dB is 1/10 of a Bel, it takes 10 times the *number of* Bels to get the *number of* decibels.  Thx!

Comment: The final conclusion is (by definition) 1 Bel = log10(P2/P1) and (by definition) 1dB = 10log10(P2/P1), so therefore 1 dB = 10 Bels. So those who assert that 1 dB is a tenth of a Bel are apparently in error.

Answer (score 0):

because A deciBel is equal to deci=1/10 of a Bel  => B=1/10dB 
Now, if this equation multiply x10 from both side => 10B=dB 
Therefore when we have 5B it must be 50dB because dB is 10 times smaller than B.

Mehrdad

Answer (score -1):

A bel is defined by using the formula: $$\log (x÷y)$$

So, if we compare 2 power ratios... Say 10 and 1; then our Bel = log (10÷1) = log (10) = 1
Similarly, if we compare 100 and 1; then our Bel = log (100÷1) = log (100) = 2

A Decibel is 1/10th of a Bel. Which means, there are 10 Decibels in 1 Bel.

So for the same ratios...
10:1 = 1 Bel OR 10 decibels;
100:1 = 2 Bels OR 20 decibels; and
1000:1 = 3 Bels OR 30 decibels.

As you see, for every Bel, we get an equivalent value of 10 Decibels.

Meaning…
If our Bel value = 1, our dB value = 10.
If our Bel value = 2, our dB value = 10 x 2 = 20.
If our Bel value = 3, our dB value = 10 x 3 = 30.

Which means, in other for us to get our Decibel value, we need to multiply our Bel value by 10.

So effectively, if we were to compute a formula for decibels directly, we can say that...

dB = 10 x log (x÷y)